# WCAG Anchor link

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I've been trying to find in the WCAG or WAI guidelines the appropriate way to create a link anchor.

I currently have a site that has anchors like these:

`<h2><a name="blah" id="blah">Blah H2 Content</a></h2>`

but since I don't want to add unnecessary CSS just to cancel any anchor (no, they're not all in titles), I was wondering if this is accessible or if it violates WCAG or WAI-ARIA guidelines:

`<h2><a name="blah" id="blah"></a>Blah H2 Content</h2>`

Comment: By those guidelines, is there anything wrong with just using `<h2 id="blah">Blah H2 Content</h2>`? After all, that ids on arbitrary elements can be used as anchor points was specified in HTML 4.01 already. And everything else, using additional `a` elements, I’d consider just unnecessary bloat-y, unless there was a very specific reason to use them.

Comment: I'm not the only user working on the site, so for conformity reasons `<a>` tags were chosen with `name` and `id` attributes (yes, I know `name` is deprecated) over using simply ids on titles and span tags. What I'm wondering is with this restriction, what is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible options I'd suggest, but first what I wouldn't recommend is having the empty anchor tag - `<a name="blah" id="blah"></a>`. With this the anchor points to nothing, so if a screen reader attempts to extract a range of a tgas to it can determine what is in the page, this will be meaningless.

### Option 1. Use the `id` against a heading.

```
<h2 id="blah">Blah H2 Content</h2>
```

If you want to have an anchor point against a heading, point it to that heading. Whith this in effect, you can stil use `example.html/mypage.html#blah` to land at the correct point.

### Option 2. Add a `href` so the anchor is useful.

```
<h2><a name="blah" id="blah" href="#blah">Blah H2 Content</a></h2>
```

If the anchor is useful to have for users, make it so they can get to it easily. By adding the `href` attribute, a user can right click and get a link to that point in the document, middle click to focus a new tab on the point and share a link to that specific part of the document with another person.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know there's any specific advice, but in WCAG 2.0 HTML and XHTML Techniques, there's an example of the use of an empty `<a>` element for this purpose. See [H86](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/html.html#H86), beneath the ASCII butterfly.

So you should be fine.

Comment: That entire subsection is awesome. "H86: Providing text alternatives for ASCII art, emoticons, and leetspeak"